# What is the best way to get rid of the ants from the box of clarified butter?

Tags: food-safety

The clarified butter is in a ***semi solid*** state in a transparent plastic box covered with a screw type lid.

I don't know how the ants went inside but now I can see those ants roaming inside the box - over and inside the clarified butter.

I was thinking of heating the butter and thus melting it down and then I could simply use a tea strainer to filter the ants out, but I think that this process will kill the ants and then I'll have dead bodies of ants and probably the juices from their bodies inside the butter which I find disgusting.

What is the way to get rid of them?

Comment: You're worried about the bodies, but did you ask the ants if they've been good and wiped their feet before entering your jar?

Comment: I would probably just call it quits and throw out the whole pack - who knows where those ants have been?

Comment: what type of ants do you have in your area?  If it's a variety that people eat anyway, it might not be as bad.  We have odorous ants around here, which smell nasty, so I'm guessing taste nasty, too.

Comment: Eating ants = lots of beneficial proteins, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to get rid of the ants? Toss the ants and the butter in the trash or a trash bag that you can quickly seal to prevent the ants from spreading around your house. Then, wash the container and check it for any holes or openings where the ants could have gotten in through (can do a water test - fill it with water and see if any water escapes). Then, go out and buy fresh butter.

Answer (score 1):

I know that I'm very late in giving a reply, but I also faced the same problem. What I did was to keep the ghee in sunlight; when it melted, I filtered it, then boiled it to prevent any germs.

Comment: You boiled the ghee?? That might deteriorate the quality of the fat and even affect the flavor.